# Difference between a denormalized PK and a compound PK in a key-value lookup situation?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-schema

I have a situation where there will be a lookup table for URL aliases for multiple sites. Each site is considered it's own namespace, so duplicate aliases are fine as long as they are in different sites.

My question is when storing this information, is there a performance difference in PostgreSQL between storing the data like this:

```
____________________________________
|Alias(PK)      | Page_Object(FK)  |
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|namespace.alias|actual page       |
```

vs:

```
_________________________________________
|Namespace(CK)|Alias(CK)|Page_Object(FK)|
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|namespace    |alias    |actual page    |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is wrong?

This isn't a performance problem, it's a correctness problem.

If the alias is unique only within a given namespace, then you need a composite unique index. It's up to you if you add a surrogate primary key, then create a `UNIQUE(namespace, alias)` constraint, or if you just have `PRIMARY KEY(namespace, alias)` but you need one of those two. Many stupid ORMs insist on having single-col keys, so if you're working with something like Rails you'll face much less suffering if you give in to its demands, create a surrogate primary key, and then a unique constraint over the two real keys.

Performance wise, there's not much difference anyway. The index might be a little bigger, but not tons, and that's all that really changes.

Comment: This is basically what I encountered, the second option with a composite key actually lets me accomplish more useful work anyways, such as selecting over a specific namespace. Thanks!